# Does the subshell run concurrent?

Tags: bash, shell

I have the following shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "Clone CHARTS repo"
LC_CODE=$(git clone https://"$GIT_USER":"$GIT_AT"@"$CHARTS_URL";echo $?)
if [ "$LC_CODE" -ne 0 ]; then
  echo "Could not find $CHARTS_URL"
  exit 1
fi

echo "Clone GITOPS repo"
LC_CODE=$(git clone https://"$GIT_USER":"$GIT_AT"@"$GITOPS_URL";echo $?)
if [ "$LC_CODE" -ne 0 ]; then
  echo "Could not find $GITOPS_URL"
  exit 1
fi
```

and have a question regarding to `$(...)`.

`$(...)` starts a new subshell. Does it mean, it starts a new thread to run the command, for instance `$(git clone https://"$GIT_USER":"$GIT_AT"@"$CHARTS_URL";echo $?)` or shell runs code always sequential?

Comment: Your  code is creating a subshell but not putting it in background hence everything runs sequentially

Comment: @zero_coding : There is a simple reason why the child process can not run possibly run in parallel here: In your parent process, you are collecting the stdout of the child and store it in the variable, and you use this value in the very next statement. If the processes would run in parallel, `LC_CODE` would be incomplete.

Comment: @zero_coding : Also, there is no way to do multi-**threading** in bash or - as in your case - in sh. Parallelism is only exposed on the process level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `$(...)` a new sub-shell will be created, but the parent shell will wait for the sub-shell to complete. Effectively making the code execute sequentially.

Side note: there is no need to use process substitution here. Consider the alternative:

```
echo "Clone CHARTS repo"
if ! git clone https://"$GIT_USER":"$GIT_AT"@"$CHARTS_URL" ; then 
  echo "Could not find $CHARTS_URL"
  exit 1
fi
```

Which will avoid the explicit sub-shell.